# Signed-digit representations

Tags: number-systems

I've been reading about [signed-digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed-digit_representation) representations of numbers and I wanted to confirm that my general understanding was correct.

As I understand it, a signed-digit representation allows for fast addition of integers, however as a consequence we now have **non-unique** representations of numbers. If we select the signed digit representation of [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary)
however, there is a special representation called the [Non-Adjacent form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-adjacent_form) that guarantees a **unique** representation of any number.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out on my own, the Non-Adjacent Form isn't in base ternary, its a special case of binary using three symbols